# How To Change Gradle "run" task (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown)

Tags: java, gradle

I made my first gradle project using VS Code and I changed the "App" java class to another name and moved it to a different file structure. When I run the "run" task using gradle, I get a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException," which is looking for the App file that I deleted. How do I change what class the run task executes? The file that I want to run has the main method btw

I tried navigating to the Gradle icon in the VS Code activity bar and right-clicking the "run" task, but there was no option to edit the task. I was expecting for my new class with the main method to run.

Comment: Assuming the `run` task is coming from the application plugin, you have to edit the `build.gradle` file (if using the Groovy DSL) or `build.gradle.kts` file (if using the Kotlin DSL) of the project. See [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_usage) for more information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the application plugin in your build.gradle (if you see the run task it is likely this is already in your config):

```
plugins {
    application
}
```

You can change the name and package of the class to be executed by run with:

```
application {
    mainClass = "org.gradle.sample.Main"
}
```

The config shown here is using the Kotlin syntax. For more information (and config samples using groovy syntax) check: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html